# UI TestStack White Get Value from a DataCell

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

Does anyone know how to get Vlaue from a ""DataCell(DataGridViewTextBoxCell)"?

I need to get a value from DataCell using its "Name" = "Symbol Row 0" or "RuntimeId" = "42 1966418 3 1 0"".

My current code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestStack.White;
using TestStack.White.Factory;
using TestStack.White.UIItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;

namespace UI_006
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("program1")[0].Id);
            Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("program1")[0].Id);
            Window Calcwindow = application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText("toto"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
            application.WaitWhileBusy();

        }
    }
}
```

My UISpy SceenShot:

[image: UISpy Image]

Comment: I would need to see what the Visual Tree looks like to be able to give you and answer to how to get the cell you are looking for. I would suggest using inspect to get this information instead.

Comment: Inspect is part of windows kits and can be found here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk it will generally install to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\{version}\inspect.exe. It will not show up in a windows search which is why i mention the location. This tool is the replacement for UI Spy.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this?